# Is there any behavior differences between debug apk and unsigned apk?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it just me or does debug versions run much smoother and faster than unsigned versions?

Comment: Since unsigned APKs cannot be run, yes, debug versions will run much smoother and faster. Only signed APKs can be installed on an Android device or emulator.

Answer (score -1):

debug apk or unsigned apk both are same thing ,if we run project then it runs in debug mode and the build generated is unsigned build/apk file.
There are a lot of differences in signed or unsigned versions:
If we signed a build then it is secure(code is obfuscated),faster,smaller in size and nobody can missuse the build.While in case if we have to upload the build on playstore then it must be Signed build/version.

Comment: **Signing an apk does not automatically obfuscate code!** Also every build can be misused.

Comment: if we signed a build to release then obviously Proguard must be enabled/true.Can you decompile the apk file entire source code even java classes ? If is there any way please share.

Comment: Apks don't have to be proguarded to be released. Every apk decompiler can restore the source code (as far as it is included in the class files, e.g. comments cannot be retained).

Comment: Can you please share link to decompile the apk file.i want to decompile whatsapp apk file....